# Attempt to de-reference a null object (at standardSetController)

Tags: apex, query, standardsetcontroller

When I'm trying to open the VF I'm getting the error :

> Attempt to de-reference a null object 
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

The following is my VF Page :

```
<apex:page controller="AccountTable" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
<apex:form id="myform">
    <apex:pageBlock >
       Please Select A Dealer To Add As Participating Dealer : <apex:selectList value="{!regionValue}" size="1" >
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!dropDown}" rerender="myform"/>
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!regionOptions}"/> 
       </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock id="table" rendered="{!if(panelStopper = true,true,false)}">
        Filter 
       <p> Dealer Type     <apex:inputText value="{!dealerType}"/> </p>
       <p>  Dealer Code    <apex:inputText value="{!dealerCode}"/> </p>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!SearchLogic}" reRender="myform" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:outputPanel id="accounts">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Account}" var="cc" id="page">
                <apex:column headerValue="Choose Account">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cc.bool}"/>
                </apex:column><apex:column value="{!cc.con.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cc.con.City__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cc.con.Dealer_GC_Code__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cc.con.Phone  }"/>
            </apex:pageblocktable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="<<" action="{!first}" reRender="accounts" />
                <apex:commandButton value="<" action="{!previous}" reRender="accounts" />
                <apex:commandButton value=">" action="{!next}" reRender="accounts" />
                <apex:commandButton value=">>" action="{!last}" reRender="accounts" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:outputText >Page Number {!pageNumber} </apex:outputText>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!clickMe}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"  onclick="window.parent.box.hide()" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!display}">
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!selectedList}" var="w" >
                <apex:column value="{!w.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

The following is my controller page :

```
Public class AccountTable{
public String size { get; set; }

//This is Our collection of the class/wrapper objects AddingParticipatingDealer 
Public List<AddingParticipatingDealer> wrapperlist{get;set;}
Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}

// Create a new Map to verify whether the Account is already added in the Map
Map <id,Account> SelectedAccountMap = new Map <id,Account>();

public boolean display{get;set;}
public list<Account> selectedList {get;set;}
public String regionValue {get;set;}    
public List<SelectOption> regionOptions {get;set;}
public String dealerType {get;set;}
public String dealerCode {get;set;} 
public Boolean panelStopper {get;set;}

public AccountTable(){ 
    regionOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    regionOptions.add(new SelectOption('aid','All Dealer'));
    regionOptions.add(new SelectOption('sid','Select A Dealer'));
    panelStopper = false;
}

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {get;set;}

//Returns a list of wrapper objects for the sObjects in the current page set
Public Void dropDown(){
    if(regionValue == 'sid' ){
        panelStopper = true;
    } 
    else{
        panelStopper = false;
    }
}

Public void SearchLogic(){
    Setcon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select Name,Dealer_Type__c,Dealer_GC_Code__c from Account Where Dealer_Type__c = :dealerType AND Dealer_GC_Code__c=:dealerCode]));
    setCon.setpagesize(10);
    noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
    getAccount();
}

Public List<AddingParticipatingDealer> getAccount(){
    getSelectedAccount();
    wrapperlist = new List <AddingParticipatingDealer >();
    //The below line number is 48
    for(Account cc : (List<Account>)Setcon.getRecords()){ //In debug log it was showing error at this line
        AddingParticipatingDealer wrapAcc = new AddingParticipatingDealer();
        wrapAcc.con = cc;               // Holding Account
        if(SelectedAccountMap.containsKey(cc.Id)){
            wrapAcc.bool = true;    // check if Checkbox is checked in vf page    
        }
        else{
            wrapAcc.bool = false;    // Used as Checkbox in vf page, default is not selected
        }
        wrapperlist.add(wrapAcc);
    }
    return wrapperlist;
}

public void getSelectedAccount(){
    if(wrapperlist!=null){
        for(AddingParticipatingDealer  wr:wrapperlist){
            if(wr.bool == true){
                SelectedAccountMap.put(wr.con.id,wr.con); // Add the selected Account id in to 
            }
            else{
                SelectedAccountMap.remove(wr.con.id); // If you uncheck the Account, remove it from the selectedAccountMap
            }
        }

    }

}

public void first(){
    Setcon.first();
    system.debug('++++++++++++++First'+Setcon);
}

 // returns the last page of records
 public void last() {
     Setcon.last();
 }

// returns the previous page of records
 public void previous() {
     Setcon.previous();
 }

//disable first and prev button
public Boolean hasPrevious {
    get {
        return Setcon.getHasPrevious();
    }
    set;
}

//display the next page of records
public void next() {
    Setcon.next();
    system.debug('++++++++++++++Next'+Setcon);
}

//disable the next and last buttons
public Boolean hasnext {
    get {
        return Setcon.getHasNext();
    }
    set;
}

public void clickMe(){
    display = true;
    getSelectedAccount();
    selectedList = SelectedAccountMap.values();
}

public integer pageNumber{
    get{
        return Setcon.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}

Public class AddingParticipatingDealer{
    Public Account con{get;set;}
    Public boolean bool{get;set;}
}
```

}

I'm getting the error at line 48 column 1

Comment: And which line is 48?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because setCon is still null at the point where you're trying to access it. You can fix this by updating your constructor:

```
public AccountTable(){ 
    regionOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    regionOptions.add(new SelectOption('aid','All Dealer'));
    regionOptions.add(new SelectOption('sid','Select A Dealer'));
    panelStopper = false;
    SearchLogic();
}
```

Comment: That's working.. and can you please explain me in detail why this happen.

Comment: @Lokesh You have to initialize a variable before you can use it. The constructor is the typical place where one would initialize their variables.